# Get WordPress posts by tag Id in RSS

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I Get WordPress posts by tag Id in RSS?

We have something like http://example.com/feed?cat=2 for categories but why there is no such thing as:-

http://example.com/feed?tag=2 ? like we do with categories?

Is there a way to add this functionality if it doesn't exist?

Comment: I will ask a cheeky question. Have you noticed something strange when you restrict it to 2 'categories'? The tags are also included in categories, for example? :D

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hook to your functions.php in WordPress theme file with some custom function to add a custom feed that gets posts by tag.
Here is an example of such a hook function.

```
add_action('init', function () {
    add_feed('my_feed', 'my_feed_markup');
});

function my_feed_markup()
{
    do_action('my_before_feed');
    header('Content-Type: ' . feed_content_type('rss') . '; charset=' . get_option('blog_charset'), true);
    status_header(200);
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

    global $wp_query;


    $tag = isset($_GET['tag']) ? $_GET['tag'] : '';


    $original_query = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = null;
    $args = array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'tag' => $tag);
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>

    <rss version="2.0" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/">
        <channel>
            <title>site.ru</title>
            <link>
            http://example.com/my_feed</link>
            <description>My new feed</description>
            <lastBuildDate>Tue, 28 Feb 2020 13:00:41 +0000</lastBuildDate>
            <language>ru-RU</language>
            <sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
            <sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency>

            <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <item>
                        <title><?php the_title(); ?></title>
                        <description>
                            <![CDATA[ <?php the_content(); ?> ]]>
                        </description>
                    </item>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>


        </channel>
    </rss>

<?php
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = $original_query;
    wp_reset_postdata();

    exit;
}
```

And you can get access to this custom feed by link like this  http://example.com/?feed=my_feed&tag=tag2

Comment: Sorry but this is not working!

Here is:- http://saviortv.tv/?feed=rss2&tag=399

and also:- http://saviortv.tv/?feed=rss2&tag=tag399

Also how can I make <lastBuildDate> dynamic and not hardcoded?